# NSNumbers are inaccurate when retrieved using core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnumber

This is a little odd to me, but when I perform basic division on a float I get inaccurate approximations. This isn't a huge deal because I can truncate the number, but I'm just curious as to why NSNumbers behave this way. Sample code included...

```
NSString *stringNumber = @"2782";
float ratio = [stringNumber floatValue]/10000;
NSNumber *sizeRatio = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:ratio];

//core data save...
```

on subsequent loads the number reads: 0.2782000005245209

Any ideas? Google hasn't been very helpful because it keeps showing me results for "number" instead of "nsnumber"

Comment: It has nothing to do with NSNumber and everything to do floating point numbers.

Answer (score 4):

This is normal for any floating point numbers

See [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)

Comment: I can understand this when approximating messy numbers, but simply dividing by 10000 seems a little silly.

Comment: @pir 10000 decimal is 10011100010000 in binary - not such a round number

Answer (score 0):

It turns out using floats results in rather inaccurate results on iOS. I've had much better success using doubles instead.

Comment: That's what doubles are for. And it's all floating point calculations. There's nothing special about iOS.